# Date type updation and data updation to a specific format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I've data in date field as `5/1/2012`, it is of type `varchar`

I need to alter the column as date and update the date as `2012-05-01`

Any idea?

Comment: u r using sqlserver 2008/2012 or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

```
 STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%Y-%d-%m')
```

try this in your query....

Comment: ALTER TABLE timedim MODIFY COLUMN datecol date.This is not working since there is data Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '6/13/12' for column 'date' at row 133 getting this error

Comment: have u checked the format but??? as if in question u wrote year as 2012 and in error year is just 12.

Comment: i already have data in the table  as 6/13/12  and need to change to 2012-06-13

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to modify the table column_type perform:

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name date

But note that Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type

So if 5/1/2012 is the input value already in the table, it will be converted to 0000-00-00

Please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html for details